# Getting every combination of two Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Let's say I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person':[1,1,2,2,3], 'sub_id':[20,21,21,21,21], 'otherval':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'other_stuff':[1,1,1,1,1]}, columns=['person','sub_id','otherval','other_stuff'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sub_id':[20,21,22,23,24,25], 'otherval':[8,9,10,11,12,13]})
```

I want each level of `person` in `df1` to have all levels of `sub_id` (including any duplicates) and their respective `otherval` from `df2`. In other words, my merged result should look like:

```
person    sub_id    otherval    other_stuff
1         20        8           1
1         21        9           NaN
1         22        10          NaN
1         23        11          Nan
1         24        12          NaN
1         25        13          NaN
2         20        8           NaN
2         21        9           1
2         21        9           1
2         22        10          NaN
2         23        11          NaN
2         24        12          NaN
2         25        13          NaN
3         20        8           NaN
3         21        9           1
3         22        10          NaN
3         23        11          NaN
3         24        12          NaN
3         25        13          NaN
```

Notice how `person==2` has *two* rows where `sub_id==21`.

Comment: Please fix the definition `df1`, all columns must have the same length.

Comment: @Abdou Just fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Try `df1.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: pd.merge(x,df2, on='sub_id', how='right')).reset_index(level = (0,1), drop = True).ffill()`.

Comment: @Abdou I believe that works! Except I don't want to forward-fill all my columns; just the `person` column.

Comment: `df1.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: pd.merge(x,df2, on='sub_id', how='right')).reset_index(level = (0,1), drop = True)` gets your desired output but you have to fill the `person` with the `.ffill()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired output with the following:

```
df3 = df1.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: pd.merge(x,df2, on='sub_id', how='right')).reset_index(level = (0,1), drop = True)
df3.person = df3.person.ffill().astype(int)
print df3
```

That should yield:

```
#     person  sub_id  otherval_x  other_stuff  otherval_y
# 0        1      20         NaN          1.0           8
# 1        1      21         NaN          1.0           9
# 2        1      22         NaN          NaN          10
# 3        1      23         NaN          NaN          11
# 4        1      24         NaN          NaN          12
# 5        1      25         NaN          NaN          13
# 6        2      21         NaN          1.0           9
# 7        2      21         NaN          1.0           9
# 8        2      20         NaN          NaN           8
# 9        2      22         NaN          NaN          10
# 10       2      23         NaN          NaN          11
# 11       2      24         NaN          NaN          12
# 12       2      25         NaN          NaN          13
# 13       3      21         NaN          1.0           9
# 14       3      20         NaN          NaN           8
# 15       3      22         NaN          NaN          10
# 16       3      23         NaN          NaN          11
# 17       3      24         NaN          NaN          12
# 18       3      25         NaN          NaN          13
```

I hope that helps.